# Type '{id:number, name:string}' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to mock data with my custom model type.

**Model**

```
export class CategoryModel {
  /**
  * Properties
  */
  public id : number;
  public name : string;

  /**
  * Getters
  */
  get Id():number{
    return this.id;
  }
  get Name():string {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
  * Setters
  */
  set Id(id:number){
    this.id = id;
  }
  set Name(name:string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  constructor(id:number,name:string)
  {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
  }

}
```

**Mock**

```
import { CategoryModel } from '../models/category';

export const CATEGORIES: CategoryModel[{id:number, name:string}] = [
  { id: 0, name: "rzrzr"},
  { id: 1, name: "rerr"},
  { id: 2, name: "aze"}
];
```

But I have an error in these file saying:

> Type '{id:number, name:string}' cannot be used as an index type

When I try this:

```
import { CategoryModel } from '../models/category';

export const CATEGORIES: CategoryModel[] = [
  { id: 0, name: "rzrzr"},
  { id: 1, name: "rerr"},
  { id: 2, name: "aze"}
];
```

I have this error:

> Type '{id:number, name:string}' is not assignable to type 'CategoryModel[]'. Type '{id:number, name:string}' is not assignable to type 'CategoryModel'. Property 'Id' is missing in type '{id:number, name:string}'

Do you have any hints? I guess I'm missing how to pass my model constructor params to my mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake here:

```
CategoryModel[{id:number, name:string}]
```

`CategoryModel` is already defined as `Object` which has properties `id` and `name`. So, you should simply declare it as `CategoryModel[]`:

```
import { CategoryModel } from '../models/category';

export const CATEGORIES: CategoryModel[] = [
  { id: 0, name: "rzrzr"},
  { id: 1, name: "rerr"},
  { id: 2, name: "aze"}
];
```

Also, you created constructor for `CategoryModel`, so you should use it while adding items to your array:

```
export const CATEGORIES: CategoryModel[] = [
  new CategoryModel(0, "rzrzr"),
  new CategoryModel(1, "rerr"),
  new CategoryModel(2, "aze")
];
```

Comment: Hello I already  try it but i have another error , i update my question

Comment: Thank you, i feel so dumb, i orgot to use it  :) , i 'll accept your ansxer in few minutes